# Error calling swi-prolog file

Tags: python, ffi, swi-prolog

I am trying to make call to swi-prolog file from python. The ode is very simple but it gives this error:

`Exception AttributeError: 'swipl_qid' in <bound method _QueryWrapper.__del__ of <pyswip.prolog._QueryWrapper object at 0x8fbe26c>> ignored`

**python:**

```
self.prolog_rule_identify = Prolog()
self.prolog_rule_identify.consult("anstype_rule.pro")
def process_pyswip(self, post_script_link_list,read_str):
    for linking in post_script_link_list:
        sub_link = re.search('\((.*?)\)',linking).group(1)
        linkage = "linkage('"+str(read_str)+"', '"+ str(sub_link) +"')"
        self.prolog_rule_identify.assertz(linkage)
    prolog_output_subjobj = self.prolog_rule_identify.query("anstype_rule(ANSTYPE)")
```

**prolog:**

```
rule_first_question(QUERY, LINK):-
    (
        (
            writeln(QUERY),
            nb_linkval(result , 'Person')
        )
    ).    
anstype_rule(ANSTYPE):-
    linkage(QUERY, LINK),
    (
        (
            rule_first_question(QUERY, LINK) ->
                nb_getval(rule, RULE)
                ; nb_linkval(rule, 'Man'), nb_getval(rule, RULE)
        )
    ).
```

error :

```
Exception AttributeError: 'swipl_qid' in <bound method _QueryWrapper.__del__ of <pyswip.prolog._QueryWrapper object at 0x8fbe26c>> ignored
```